# how to reset all the select box inside a div onclick of a button?

Tags: javascript, input

in my form

```
<div class="container">
    <select name="sel1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="sel2">
        <option value="0">Zero</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="resetAll()" value="Reset"/>
```

i need to reset both **sel1,sel2** to default values. ie **selectedIndex = 0;**

```
function resetAll()
{
     //what should i write here to do this
}
```

i have more than 20 selectboxes. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an id to the container item, so you can easily reference it. This way you only reset the select boxes that reside in it, and not any other ones you may have on the page:

```
function resetAll() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var children = container.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should work for any number of `drop downs`

```
function resetAll()
{
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var len = selects.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        selects[i].selectedIndex=0;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LAaRv/1/

**UPDATE:**

If you want to reset only "sel1" and "sel2" then try this,

```
function resetAll()
{
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var len = selects.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(selects[i].name == "sel1" || selects[i].name == "sel2"){
           selects[i].selectedIndex=0;
        }
    }
} ​
```

​

Comment: This resets **all** the <select> elements on the page, Nevin only wants to reset the ones from the container element.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Without using any for loop -

For First Index -

```
 $("select").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 });
```

For Empty Selection -

```
 $("select").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = -1 });
```

<kbd>[PLUNKER EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/vy7jAt1L56bVPdpUIm0I?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var secondCombo = document.getElementsByName("sel1")[0];
secondCombo.value = 0;
```